# Woocommerce Custom JS Events not detected with All Products Gutenberg block

Tags: ajax, woocommerce, gutenberg-blocks

I am using the following code snippet to detect when a product from All Products Gutenberg block has been added to cart via the add to cart button. However, when I click on any of the add to cart buttons, nothing happens and no error message in console:

```
// Adjust added to cart behavior for the homepage pattern for better ui
$( 'body' ).on( 'wc_fragments_loaded added_to_cart', function( ) {
    $( document ).ajaxSuccess( function( event, xhr, settings ) {
        if ( settings.url.indexOf( '?wc-ajax=add_to_cart' ) !== -1 ) {
            $( this.activeElement ).hide();
            $( this.activeElement ).next().addClass( 'add_to_cart_button wp-element-button' );
        }
    } );
} );
```

I have used this code before to successfully capture custom events from WooCommerce but is it working on Gutenberg blocks and how to do it properly?

Answer (score 4):

Are you using the new checkout and mini cart? (woocommerce/woocommerce-blocks) If so the problem is that woocommerce-blocks use REST API to add products to the cart and to update mini cart and checkout. Fragments and Ajax are not used.

Try this:

```
document.body.addEventListener('wc-blocks_added_to_cart', () => {
        console.log('success')
});
```

You can read the documentation here https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce-blocks

Comment: Hello! Following this line, would you know how to inform the events for removing the item from the cart, as well as changing the quantity of items in the product?